# Overriding a method of data.table - failing to perfectly forward arguments

Tags: r, data.table

I'm able to successfully modify the behaviour of `[.data.frame`, but fail to do so for `[.data.table`.

For data.frame:

```
# Exact same signature as "[.data.frame" :
"[.my.data.frame" <- function (x, i, j, 
                               drop = if (missing(i)) TRUE 
                                      else length(cols) == 1) {
  if(!missing(j) && j==8 ) {
    cat("Oy vey\n")
  }
  NextMethod()
}

df <- data.frame(a=1,b=2)
class(df) <- c("my.data.frame", class(df))

# Works as expected:
df[1,2]  # 2
df[1,8]  # Oy Vey    NULL
df[1,]   # 1 2
```

However, for (the considerably more complicated) data.table:

```
# Exact same signature as "[.data.table" :
"[.my.data.table" <- function (x, i, j, by, keyby, with = TRUE, nomatch = getOption("datatable.nomatch"), 
                               mult = "all", roll = FALSE, 
                               rollends = if (roll == "nearest") c(TRUE, TRUE) 
                                          else if (roll >= 0) c(FALSE, TRUE) else c(TRUE, FALSE), 
                               which = FALSE, .SDcols, verbose = getOption("datatable.verbose"), 
                               allow.cartesian = getOption("datatable.allow.cartesian"), 
                               drop = NULL, on = NULL) {
  if(!missing(j) && j==8 ) {
    cat("Oy vey\n")
  }
  NextMethod()
}

dt <- data.table(a=1,b=2)
class(dt) <- c("my.data.table", class(dt))

dt[1,2]   # ERROR:  i is not found in calling scope and it is not a column of type logical. When the first argument inside DT[...] is a single symbol, data.table looks for it in calling scope.
```

I know better than to [pass arguments to NextMethod](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/44). It looks like I must call `[.data.table` explicitly, capture and pass the arguments as unevaluated promises - but all my attempts with `quote`, `substitute` or `match.call` have so far failed.   Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution, posting here in hope someone might improve on it.

```
"[.my.data.table" <- function (x, ...) {

  # Modifications and tests galore - which can be tricky with this signature

  class(x) <- class(x)[-1]
  ret <- x[...]
  class(x) <- c("my.data.table", class(x))
  ret
}
```

I still consider this partial, because actually doing something in the function probably involves at least something like `arglist <- list(...)`, and this fails when `[` is called like this -

```
dt[1,]
```

Other directions are still very welcome.